# how to order inputs horizontally within ArrayImput and SimpleFormIterator

Tags: react-admin

Is it possible to order inputs horizontally within  ArrayImput and SimpleFormIterator? I know that the default is vertical. Thanks

See image of vertical inputs inside ArrayInputs here. Can the inputs be arranged horizontally? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, the `ArrayInput` is made using **material-ui** which comes with its style way. For instance, you can play with elements `root`, `form` etc...

```js
const useIteratorStyle = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  line: {
    border: 0,
  },
}));

const iteratorClasses = useIteratorStyle();

<ArrayInput {...props}>
  <SimpleFormIterator classes={iteratorWithIndexClasses}>
  ...
  </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

Gives me something like

[image]

You can override each property of the `useStyles` object defined in the `SimpleFormIterator`: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/SimpleFormIterator.tsx

Comment: Thanks Striped as usual

Answer (score 0):

`Inline` prop has been introduced in [version 4.3](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/releases/tag/v4.3.0). It should work like that

```
<ArrayInput {...props}>
 <SimpleFormIterator inline>
 ...
 </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```